# Huffman coding for Lossless Compression

Tags: lossless-compression, huffman-code

I really need help with Huffman Coding for Lossless compression. I have an exam coming up and need to understand this, does anyone know of easy tutorials made to understand this, or could someone explain.

The questions in the exam are likely to be:

Suppose the alphabet is [A, B, C], and the known probability distribution is P(A)=0.6, 
P(B)=0.2 and P(C)=0.2. For simplicity, let’s also assume that both encoder and decoder know 
that the length of the messages is always 3, so there is no need for a terminator.

1. How many bits are needed to encode the message ACB by Huffman Coding? You need to 
   provide the Huffman tree and Huffman code for each symbol. (3 marks)
2. How many bits are needed to encode the message ACB by Arithmetic Coding? You need to 
   provide details of the encoding process. (3 marks)
3. Using the above results, discuss the advantage of Arithmetic Coding over Huffman coding.
   (1 mark)

Answers:

1. Huffman Code: A - 1, B - 01, C - 00.
   The encoding result is 10001, so 5 bits are needed. (3 marks)
2. The encoding process of Arithmetic Coding:
   Symbol Low high range
   0.0 1.0 1.0
   A 0.0 0.6 0.6
   C 0.48 0.6 0.12
   B 0.552 0.576 0.024
   The final binary codeword is 0.1001, which is 0.5625. Therefore 4 bits are needed. (3 marks)
3. In Huffman Coding, the length of the codeword for each symbol has to be an integer. But it 
   can be fractional in Arithmetic Coding. Therefore Arithmetic Coding is often more efficient 
   than Huffman Coding, as the results shown above. (1 mark)

Comment: wow, you're pretty good at guessing what your **future** assignment will be. Even down to how many marks for each question!

Comment: lol, it's a practice question, but the lecturer said this will be similar and he will only change the numbers around.

Comment: humm... okay. what are you having trouble with? this should all be covered in your textbook.

Comment: The textbook is quite tedious, it doesn't really explain it for a beginner. I am having trouble with working out for the first question, I have put the answer above. Not sure how he got the answer.

Comment: If one needs to do it on Mathematica, this could be helpful. https://www.academia.edu/19699746/Huffman_Code_on_Mathematica_using_Trees

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

If you look at the tree (top right) you'll see that each parent node is the sum of the two below it. The values at the nodes are the frequencies of the letters. Each bit in the binary  sequence is a right/left branch  in the tree.

Does that help?

I don't really have a clue about [Arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding), but it looks quite clever.

Answer (score 1):

A Huffman tree is a binary tree with the nodes representing the values with the highest distribution in the stream being compressed near the root and the values with decreasing distribution further and further away from the root, thus allowing more common values to be encoded in shorter bit strings while less common values are encoded in longer strings.

A Huffman tree is constructed as follows:

1. Build a table of entities in the source stream, with their distribution.
2. Pick the two entries in the table that have the lowest distribution.
3. Make a tree node out of these two entries.
4. Remove the entries just used from the table.
5. Add a new entry to the table with the combined distribution of the nodes just removed, as well as the tree node.
6. if there is more than one entry left in the table, go to step 2.
7. The entry left in the table is your root.

Answer (score 0):

Basic huffmann implementation can be quite ok. But, if you are building from scratch you may need more than 1 other datastructure in your toolbox to make things easier such as a minHeap and a bit vector. The basic algorithms for encoding and decoding are pretty simple. No info on comparison with arithmetic coding.

[An implementation example](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.com/2011/12/take-on-huffman-coding-algorithm-how-to.html)